# Sensor monitoring DB; Is "Metric" the correct naming for this?

Tags: database, database-design

I hope this doesn't seem like a daft question but, I'm trying to define a database model that measures various "metrics" via sensors, such as:

```
Temperature
Humidity
Pressure
Energy
```

Etc.

I've defined a relation called "Metric" for this.

The idea is then the user can add Sensors that measure a particular Metric, so the Sensor becomes related to a row in Metric.

However, there are also "switch sensors" that instead of measuring a value, they monitor whether a switch is on or off.  Generally it is for monitoring large refridgeration units, so they have things like:

```
Compressor (Run/Not-Running)
Door (Open/Closed)
Defrost (Active/Inactive)
```

Can these be considered "Metrics" too?  Would it be logical to end up with something like:

```
[Metric]
T  Temperature
P  Pressure
H  Humidity
C  Compressor
D  Door
Df Defrost

[Sensor]
UnitNo
SensorNo
MetricCode
```

Thanks.

EDIT: I'll elaborate a little further.
Basically the system allows users to add sensors to a "unit".

```
The sensors can be of the following type:
Air Temperature
Water Temperature
Product Temperature
Relative Humidity
Pressure
Energy
Compressor
Defrost
Door
```

These are physical sensors, some analog some switch-based.  The latter 3 are switch based, they are either on or off.  When a door switch is on, it is "Open", otherwise "Closed", when a Compressor switch is on it is "Running", etc.

I store readings from these sensors.  I sub-type the readings into reading_analog and reading_switch.

Originally, all the system handled was temperature, so my sensor types were actually "air", "water", "product".  I'm trying to redesign this part of the database.

I've actually renamed Metric to Quantity now after finding this page: http://www.ebyte.it/library/educards/sidimensions/SiDimensionsByCategory.html

Comment: From the physics perspective, I think a more appropriate term would be ["dimension"](http://www.mne.psu.edu/cimbala/Learning/General/units.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I think that it would be more logical to have a set of metrics:

```
Temperature
Pressure
Humidity
Running
Open
Active
```

The last three are states that you are measuring, and have a boolean value.

You might consider storing them as "states" rather than as "metrics", as they are rather different -- the latter is generally represented as a number from a continuous series, whereas the former is one of a set of discrete values (which could be more than "open" or "close" ... for example "Running", "Stopped", "Starting", "Stopping" ... etc).

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your answer.  I've elaborated my question now if you'd like to have a look.  Thanks.